# Jackson JSON JsonTypeInfo and JsonSubTypes Integer value is serialized as String to JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, java-record

In my "quest" to parse lottieFile and dotLottie JSONs into Java objects and back to identical lottieFiles (see https://lottie4j.com/), I discovered a strange effect of @JsonSubTypes.

Java 17 + Jackson 2.14.1

As I'm making an implementation on top of the Lottie data model, it's not possible to make a change in the JSON format.

It seems that the following code, causes the Integer value of `a` to become a String when converting back to JSON.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "a")
@JsonSubTypes({
      @JsonSubTypes.Type(names = {"0", "0.0"}, value = FixedBezier.class),
      @JsonSubTypes.Type(names = {"1", "1.0"}, value = AnimatedBezier.class)
})
```

This is the test result:

```
Original:     {"a": 0, "d": "test"}
Generated:    {"a": "0", "d": "test"}
```

Even when using

```
@JsonSerialize(using = IntegerSerializer.class)
```

or

```
@JsonSerialize(using = AnimatedSerializer.class)
```

With or without these `@JsonSerialize`, `"a": "0"` is generated instead of `"a": 0`. Am I missing some configuration to force the JsonSubType value to be stored as a number in the JSON? How can this be achieved?

This is my full test code, with both the `@JsonSerialize` commented to easily switch between different possible solutions...

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

import java.io.IOException;

public class BezierTest {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] jsons = new String[]{
                // jsonLottieFilesFixed
                "{\"a\":0,\"d\":\"test\"}",
                // jsonLottieFilesAnimated
                "{\"a\":1,\"d\":\"test\"}",
                // dotLottieFilesFixed
                "{\"a\":0.0,\"d\":\"test\"}",
                // dotLottieFilesAnimated
                "{\"a\":1.0,\"d\":\"test\"}"
        };
        for (String json : jsons) {
            test(json);
        }
    }

    private static void test(String json) {
        BaseBezier objectFromJson = null;
        try {
            objectFromJson = mapper.readValue(json, BaseBezier.class);
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String jsonFromObject = mapper.writeValueAsString(objectFromJson);

            System.out.println("Original:\t" + json);
            System.out.println("Generated:\t" + jsonFromObject);

            System.out.println("Is equal: " + json.equals(jsonFromObject));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            System.err.println("Json exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "a")
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(names = {"0", "0.0"}, value = FixedBezier.class),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(names = {"1", "1.0"}, value = AnimatedBezier.class)
    })
    interface BaseBezier {

    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    record FixedBezier(
            @JsonProperty("a")
            @JsonSerialize(using = AnimatedSerializer.class)
            Integer animated,

            @JsonProperty("d")
            String data

    ) implements BaseBezier {
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public record AnimatedBezier(
            @JsonProperty("a")
            // @JsonSerialize(using = AnimatedSerializer.class)
            Integer animated,

            @JsonProperty("d")
            String data
    ) implements BaseBezier {
    }

    private static class AnimatedSerializer extends JsonSerializer {
        @Override
        public void serialize(Object o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
            jsonGenerator.writeNumber((int) o);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you simplify your example to reduce the references to non-Jackson libraries - junit, skyscreamer etc. Also, which version of Jackson are you using?

Comment: good remark, the code has now been simplified to run from main. Version info has been added (= Java 17 + Jackson 2.14.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using JSON field "a" as both a type identifier:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "a")
```

and as a field identifier:

```
@JsonProperty("a")
```

Since the type identifiers have to be string values, this is what you're seeing in the resultant JSON - the type id expressed as a string.

If you change one of them to use a different field name, and update your test JSON accordingly, then it works, e.g.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "id")

// jsonLottieFilesFixed
"""
{ "id": "0", "a": 0, "d": "test"}
""",
```

with the following output:

```
Original:
{ "id": "0", "a": 0, "d": "test"}

Generated:
{"id":"0","a":0,"d":"test"}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed a working solution, but unfortunately I'm making an implementation on top of the Lottie data model. So it's not possible to make a change in the JSON format.

Comment: What you're asking is impossible though. You can't store two different fields under the same field name - they have to use different field names. Where exactly is this data model documented as I can find no mention of BaseBezier?

Comment: The code in this question is a simplification of what I try to achieve in https://github.com/lottie4j/lottie4j/tree/main/core/src/main/java/com/lottie4j/core/model/bezier. I use TDD based on https://lottiefiles.github.io/lottie-docs/shapes/#path and existing lottie-files. This way I could determine there are two different data models of Beziers based on the animated (a) value, which I defined as AnimatedBezier and FixedBezier. But nothing is "set in stone" so any alternative solution would work!

Comment: The documenation is somewhat hard to follow. It seems that in certain places in the JSON more than one structure could appear and the only way to work out which structure it is is by inspecting the field names and then matching those against known structures. If this is the case then a Jackson-style data-binding approach will not work. You would instead need a parser that iterates through the JSON tokens (or traverses over a JSON node tree), and by inspecting the next set of fields, makes decisions on what data structure to create next.

Comment: +1 regarding the documentation being hard to follow ;-) and that's what I was afraid of, my idea to use only data-binding and records will probably not work...

Comment: Yep, you could still make a data-binding approach work, but I think you would have to hand-craft the translation from JSON tokens/nodes to your data model. For a small data model this isn't too difficult. Another option might be to use a tool like https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to compile the JSON schema for Lottie (https://lottiefiles.github.io/lottie-docs/schema/) into Java pojos.

Comment: I added a JsonDeserializer "one level higher" in the Java model, and now seem to have a working solution. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Commit containing this fix: https://github.com/lottie4j/lottie4j/commit/125fc652515b21a20e5f5c063d3eea4e93fcbb22

Comment: 